# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "CordovaPlugins"

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, cocoapods

I've run into an issue with my Ionic app, noticing since Capacitor was being updated. I do have Cordova plugins installed and have followed the instructions as per the Ionic documentation when installing these into the app.

I have tried removing and updating Cocoapods, Pod install etc and nothing seems to solve this problem.

The error shows as follows:

*[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "CordovaPlugins":
In Podfile:
CordovaPlugins (from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`)
Specs satisfying the `CordovaPlugins (from` ../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.*

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `required a higher minimum deployment target`

Comment: Yes - i did try to change that in xCode. Do you have any suggested steps?

Comment: I guess you need to fix your pod file. According to document : **You may need to change the version of platform specified or specify certain versions for other plugins.**

Comment: Also please check this app for your case https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-webview-ios